# Vlookup that is searches part of the string

Tags: vlookup

I need to find a way to create a vlookup that will populate a field if the lookup table contains the values in the table array.

For example, A1 contains account number 4563399P01/f/5. A2 contains account number 43823448P01S/f/5.
I need cell B1 to display $10.00, if the account contains P01, B2 to display 12.50 if the account contains P01S.

I was able to use vlookup using the whole account number, but as new account numbers are added, they need to be added to the table array. It would be much easier to search the account number if it contains P01, P01S, G01, S021, etc, since there are limited options.

I hope that makes sense since my brain is fried. It doesn't seem like it should be that hard, but clearly it is for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help. Use the `SEARCH` and `ISNUMBER` functions to find the string you want:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("P01S",A1)), 10, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("P01",A1)), 12.5, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("G01",A1)), ...)))
```

The `SEARCH` checks for the position of the string within the account number, and the `ISNUMBER` returns true if the position is a number i.e. the string has been found. You could replace the values with a `VLOOKUP` on the relevant string too. This obviously needs extending for the remainder of the strings you wish to search for.

One thing to be careful of is when you have P01 and P01S. The search will find P01 in accounts that contain P01S too, so it is important to make sure you put these in the correct order - start with the P01S and if that is not found then look for P01.